# Cake php table join two fields

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm starting with php using Cakephp 4.x.

I baked a table called `Persona` (spanish for person), with two fields, `last_names` and `names`.

I set the `setDisplayField` in my `PersonaTable` to `last_names` but I want to join it with `names`, so the output would be:

```
Doe, John
```

The relevant code:

```php
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('personas');
    
    /* 
     * here I want to join last_names with names
     */
    $this->setDisplayField('last_names');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
}
```

My guess is that I have to create a function in my `PersonaTable` that gives that result, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is [`Virtual entity fields`](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields):

Adding to the model this function

```
protected function _getFullName() {
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

I can access `full_name` as a field, like:

```
$persona->full_name
```